# how to get inner array from Outer array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, api

I want to pull a array from outer array.

**My result**

[image]

**I want to remove circle symbol of array**

```
{
"Success": "1",
"Message": "Subtopic Wise Questions...",
"Subtopic Questions": [
    [
        {
            "id": "93",
            "topic_id": "36",
            "name": "Cell membrane and organelle",
            "created_at": "2018-08-29 23:06:34",
            "updated_at": "2018-08-29 23:06:34",
            "q_count": "127"
        }
    ],   
]
```

}

Here is my output result of array. the

**My Controller code**

```
 foreach($findid as $v)
        {
            $count[] = DB::table('questions')
                        ->join('subtopics', 'subtopics.id', 'questions.subtopic_id')
                        ->select('subtopics.*', DB::raw('count(questions.id) as q_count'))
                        ->where('subtopic_id', $v)
                        ->get();
        }


        return response([
                    'Success' => "1",
                    'Message' => "Subtopic Wise Questions...",
                    'Subtopic Questions'   => $count
                    ]);
```

Comment: use  `$count` instead of  `$count[]`

Comment: make foreach loop through Subtopic Questions->Subtopic Questions

Comment: @JigneshJoisar if i use $count it's return only first column of result.

Comment: Seems to my you should try to fetch all required rows at once instead of one each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `first()` to obtain just an object as per your image you want to remove extra array quotes so

```
$count[] = DB::table('questions')
                    ->join('subtopics', 'subtopics.id', 'questions.subtopic_id')
                    ->select('subtopics.*', DB::raw('count(questions.id) as q_count'))
                    ->where('subtopic_id', $v)
                    ->first();
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: @KrishBhardwaj Eloquent will return an array of objects as you have displayed result it is clearly shown that its an array of objects if you dont use `toArray()` .  So if you just want to pull array not object than you will need to use `toArray()`

Comment: i used toArray() but not working to achieve result according me.

Comment: ohh okay i got it ! please check my edited answer. @KrishBhardwaj

Comment: @KrishBhardwaj QueryBuilder will return `Illuminate\Support\Collection`. @LeenaPatel Eloquent will return `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection. Not array or array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

use `whereIn` method instead of `where` method

> note only store id in array then used whereIn method

```
$count = DB::table('questions')
                ->join('subtopics', 'subtopics.id', 'questions.subtopic_id')
                ->select('subtopics.*', DB::raw('count(questions.id) as q_count'))
                ->whereIn('subtopic_id', array_wrap($findid))
                ->get();
```

> note if not working as u want restult then add `toArray()` method in
>   query like this

**$count->toArray();**

```
 return response([
               'Success' => "1",
               'Message' => "Subtopic Wise Questions...",
               'Subtopic Questions'   => $count
     ]);
```

Comment: Can replace `is_array($findid) ? $findid : [ $findid]` with `array_wrap($findid)`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is expensive. Since you are looping through array of ids, you are going to run queries `count(findid)` number of times. You can optimize and achieve the same as,

```
$count = DB::table('questions')
            ->join('subtopics', 'subtopics.id', 'questions.subtopic_id')
            ->select('subtopics.*', DB::raw('count(questions.id) as q_count'))
            ->whereIn('subtopic_id', $findid)
            ->get();


return response([
    'Success' => "1",
    'Message' => "Subtopic Wise Questions...",
    'Subtopic Questions'   => $count
]);
```